# How to validate a string is alphanumeric in an Azure Logic App?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I want to validate that a string is alphanumeric, but I'm having some trouble doing that in my logic app, especially because it seems like intersection and union take only arrays.

Any ideas? It would even do if something like `explode` existed for Strings. Anything I can do to make Strings an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the doc, you need to create an array with the values you want to combine:

```
union(createArray(1, 2, 3), createArray(1, 2, 10, 101))
```

And returns this result: [1, 2, 3, 10, 101]

However, if you want to check that a particular string is alphanumeric, this may not be the right way for it. I would prefer creating an Azure Function and calling it in your workflow. The following Azure Function code should do the trick for you:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

[FunctionName("AlphaNumericFunction")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] 
    HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    string content = req.Query["content"];

    string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
    content = content ?? data?.content;

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(content))
    {
        return new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass the content on the query string or in the request body");
    }

    Regex rg = new Regex(@"/^\w+$/");
    var isAlphaNumeric = rg.IsMatch(content);

    return (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"{isAlphaNumeric}");
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you can't create the Function App, you could use the following inline approach:

[image]

PS: replace the regex from sample to the following: ^\w+$

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-add-run-inline-code

Comment: How would I create an azure function and add it to my workflow? That sounds awesome.

Comment: pioardi shared the link in his response below: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-functions

Comment: PS: please notice that his answer shows a NodeJS function while mine is c# based.

Comment: Okay, this looks good, but creating a function will mean deploying a functionapp, and I don't think that is something we can do.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation the best option from my point of view is to create an azure function and to call the function from your logic app .
Some docs here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-functions